# How can I open an obj in blender?

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, materials, objects

I downloaded a model and want to open it in blender. I saw many tutorials on YouTube, all of them say to go to file, import and and to click on wavefront obj. I've tried this many times but it doesn't work.

My file doesn't show up in obj files. its sometimes a GLB file, and sometimes a fbx file. It constantly changes depending on where I want to open. When I try to drag into blender, it doesn't show up. I opened my obj on the 3d viewer and it showed up, but in blender it doesn't. I don't know why.

I'm a beginner and I have no clue on what to do. What can I do ?

[Model I want to import](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sasha-f6030ea6afd049fbb338b6c0ca241d7f)

Comment: Make sure the file has the .obj extension, if it doesn't you'll need to add it to the filename. Also if you can share your file I could try importing it into blender and pass you the blend project.

Comment: What filename extension does the file you want to import have?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you have done everything correctly for importing an OBJ file, which means either:

1. This isn’t an actual OBJ file (it sounds like it doesn’t even have the right file name extension, but maybe that just got removed somehow),
2. It’s corrupted (look for errors in the bottom header when importing), or
3. It actually is importing, but you’re just not seeing it for some reason: Perhaps it’s very large or very small.

As for getting into 3-D, I actually suggest you don’t start by importing someone else’s model, since they will have different building techniques than you, and I feel that could mess you up. I could be wrong, though.